# How to keep hover state on parent when on child element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have tried many solutions but nothing has worked for me. I want to make my parent element stay on the hover state when I am on the sub menu of "Company" in my specific HTML.

### My HTML

```
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="sf-with-ul">company<span class="menu-arrow"></span><em></em></a>
      <ul >
        <li><a href="#">Welcome Message</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Company Profile<span class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Our Capabilities</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="current"><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
```

### My CSS:

```
nav {
position:relative;
background:url(../images/theme/nav.png) repeat-x #e7e7e7;
min-height:68px;
margin:0;
}

.sf-menu ul {
position:absolute;
top:-999px;
display:none;
}

.sf-menu ul li {
width:100%;
}

.sf-menu li {
float:left;
position:relative;
}

.sf-menu>li>a {
display:block;
font-size:12px;
line-height:17px;
color:#2f2e2e;
font-weight:bold;
text-transform:uppercase;
width:189px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
padding:27px 0 24px;
}

.sf-menu>li>a>em {
display:block;
width:0;
position:absolute;
bottom:200%;
left:50%;
right:50%;
top:auto;
background:#fa5758;
height:3px;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
display:block;
-webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn 1s;
-o-animation:fadeIn 1s;
animation:fadeIn 1s;
}

.sf-menu>li>a:hover>em,.sf-menu>li.current>a>em,.sf-menu>li.sfHover>a>em {
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
width:100%;
}

.sf-menu>li {
border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.sf-menu>li:first-child {
border-left:none;
}

.sf-menu>li>ul,.sf-menu>li.sfHover>ul {
left:0;
top:68px;
width:190px;
z-index:99;
background:url(../images/theme/sub_ul1.png) repeat-x #676464;
padding:22px 0 24px;
}

.sf-menu>li>ul>li>a {
background:url(../images/theme/sub_li1.png) 0 -50px repeat-x;
color:#fff;
}

.sf-menu li li a:hover,.sf-menu li.sfHover li.sfHover>a {
background-position:0 0;
background-color:#b7b7b7;
color:#454545;
}

.sf-menu li li ul {
left:148px;
top:-22px;
width:190px;
z-index:99;
background:url(../images/theme/sub_ul2.png) repeat-x;
padding:22px 0 23px;
}

.sf-menu li li a {
font-size:11px;
text-transform:uppercase;
display:block;
background:url(../images/theme/sub_li2.png) 0 -50px repeat-x;
color:#454545;
padding:5px 0 5px 29px;
}

.sf-menu li li li a:hover {
background-position:0 0;
background-color:#2d2d2d;
color:#fff;
}

.sf-menu li a .menu-arrow {
display:inline-block;
width:5px;
height:3px;
text-indent:-100%;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
background:url(../images/theme/menu_arrow.png) no-repeat;
vertical-align:middle;
margin:-3px 0 0 5px;
}

.sf-menu a:hover .menu-arrow,.sf-menu li.current>a .menu-arrow,.sf-menu .sfHover>a:hover
.menu-arrow {
background-position:0;
}

.sf-menu>li>a,.sf-menu em,.list1 a,.button,footer a {
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease;
-o-transition:all .5s ease;
transition:all .5s ease;
}

ul li>ul,#menu-icon {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You can use jQury or js ,when hove on the child class change the change or add class :hover for the parent one.

Comment: Can i use css to do this ?

Comment: Please include code in your question rather than just a link to a demo. (It might break in the future). It would also be nice if you only included the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate the issue. Also be specific about what's happening now and what you want to happen instead. Welcome to stack overflow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple CSS solution for you:

```
.sf-menu > li:hover > a {
  background: #444;
}
```

I am just changing the background here for illustrative purposes. I placed it at the bottom of your CSS and when I hover over Company and use the dropdown below it, the main anchor stays as if it's hovered.

Let me know if that works for you too, and if it does don't forget to accept the answer or upvote so people know what works.

### [Here is an image of that working](http://tinypic.com/r/34yuwjk/5)

Since your problem was specific about keeping that orange bar there, you must first know that the orange bar was being applied with jQuery with a class called `.sfHover`... so then the parent `<li>` has this class it makes the orange bar remain active there.

### [The Fiddle with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/VdpJR/)

Comment: sorry but don't my answer i want . I want keep orginal parent's hover(in this case hover of company)

Comment: That's the answer he gave you. The `ul` submenu is a descendant of the parent `li`, so when the `ul` is hovered it counts as a hover event on the parent `li` too.  This code targets that parent `li`'s immediate `a` child, which is the top level nav item.  Just give this the same styles as your top level `a:hover`.  There is no need for JS here.

Comment: Yep, @Ennui, well said. Just for illustrative purposes I'm adding an image. http://tinypic.com/r/34yuwjk/5

Comment: sorry can i don't know this ! Actual i want my menu like http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/42677.html but i can't do that . When on hover on child parent's hover is disappear.

Comment: Well, you would simply replace my `background: #444;` CSS property to match the hover animation and styling of the red bar. The main idea is there, you simply need to extend it to your own design.

Comment: .sf-menu > li:hover > a {display:block;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:200%;
  left:50%;
  right:50%;
  top:auto;
  background:#fa5758;
  height:3px;} But it don't work corectlly

Comment: The problem is that you need jQuery to do this approach the same was as the template monster menu. I added a jsFiddle to my answer at the bottom with the solution you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery following one is may be help you :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#child').hover(function(){     
            $('#parent').addClass('hoverClass');    
        },     
        function(){    
            $('#parent').removeClass('hoverClass');     
        });
    });
```